# External executable crashes when being launched from Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, external, executable

I am currently getting an issue with an external executable crashing when it is launched from a Python script. So far I have tried using various subprocess calls. As well as the more redundant methods such as os.system and os.startfile.

Now the exe doesn't have this issue when I call it normally from the command line or by double-clicking on it from the explorer window. I've looked around to see if other people have had a similar problem too. As far as I can tell the closest possible cause of this issue is that the child process unnecessarily hangs due to the I/O exceeding 65K. So I've tried using Popen without PIPES and I have also changed the stdout and stdin to write to temporary files to try and alleviate my problem. But unfortunately none of this has worked.

What I eventually want to do is be able to autorun this executable several times with various outputs provided by xmls. Everything else is pretty much in place, including the xml modifications which the executable requires. I have also tested the xml modification portion of the code as a standalone script to make sure that this isn't the issue.

Due to the nature of script I am a bit reluctant to put up any actual code up on the net as the company I work for is a bit strict when it comes to showing code. I would ask my colleagues if I could but unfortunately I'm the only one here who actually has used python.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've not had any response I've kind of gone down a different route with this. Rather than relying on the subprocess module to call the exe I have moved that logic out into a batch file. The xmls are still modified by the python script and most of the logic is still handled in script. It's not what ideally would have liked from the program but it will have to do.

Thanks to anybody who gave this some thought and tried to at least look for an alternative. Even if nobody answered.